# after confirm or cancel data upload from my excel file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

I'am developing an ASP MVC 5 web application using SQL Server. I upload data from excel file  via a button with javascript function.

I have a button validate and I add sweet alert warning to notify the user that he is about to delete the data in base but the problem that I even if I click button cancel or yes the upload of data works which is not the case to cancel.

i use the submit button
This is my View :

```
<button id="adminButton" class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i> Lecture en cours" onclick="ChargementDonnes()">
```

My Controller :

```
public ActionResult LoadDatainShowIndex()
    {
        try
        {
            LoadData();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //                Response.StatusCode = 406; // Or any other proper status code.
            Response.Write(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

my javascript code:

```
function ChargementDonnes() {

swal({
    title: "Etes vous sur",
    text: "Vous êtes sur le point de recharger tous les données de la base. Continuer ?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    confirmButtonText: "Oui",
    cancelButtonText: "Non",
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    closeOnConfirm: true
}).then(
    function() {

        console.log("Appel de la méthode LoadData");
        $('#adminButton').button('loading');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/LoadDatainShowIndex',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result)
            {

                if (result === "True") {
                    console.log(1);
                   // $('#adminButton').button('reset');

                    Swal({
                        title: "Succès !",
                        type: 'success',
                        showCancelButton: false,
                        confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        closeOnConfirm: true

                    });
                    console.log(2);
                }



            },
            error: function(x, y, z) {
                $('#adminButton').button('reset');
                console.log(3);
                SendMessageToUser('Chargement des données depuis Excel', 'erreur');
            }
        });
    }

);
```

}

Comment: its hard for me to tell what you're saying the problem is here. Can you edit to make your english to make this more clear?

Comment: @GregH 
I modified my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an if statement in `then` function of `swal`.
You should send the request only if `result.value` is true

```
swal({
        title: "Etes vous sur",
        text: "Vous êtes sur le point de recharger tous les données de la base. Continuer ?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        confirmButtonText: "Oui",
        cancelButtonText: "Non",
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        closeOnConfirm: true
    }).then(
        function(result) {

          if(result.value){
            console.log("Appel de la méthode LoadData");
            $('#adminButton').button('loading');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/LoadDatainShowIndex',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result)
                {

                    if (result === "True") {
                        console.log(1);
                       // $('#adminButton').button('reset');

                        Swal({
                            title: "Succès !",
                            type: 'success',
                            showCancelButton: false,
                            confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
                            confirmButtonText: "OK",
                            closeOnConfirm: true

                        });
                        console.log(2);
                    }



                },
                error: function(x, y, z) {
                    $('#adminButton').button('reset');
                    console.log(3);
                    SendMessageToUser('Chargement des données depuis Excel', 'erreur');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    );
```

Comment: You welcome :D You can accept the answer if it worked as expected :D

Comment: Dusan RadovanovicI have an anormal behavior when i load data i i have message error in error :fonction(x,y,z)

Comment: the problem is that it loads the data but on the return json it passes on error it I see the value of the consol.log I think the problem is on My Controller :r   (  error: function(x, y, z) {
                    $('#adminButton').button('reset');
                    console.log(3);
                    SendMessageToUser('Chargement des données depuis Excel', 'erreur');)

Comment: if error function was executed that means that you have received HTTP response with status code 4xx or 5xx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189208/discussion-between-mohammed-rasfa-and-dusan-radovanovic).